# Linear Algebra question on permutations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have a general question regarding this [article](http://chalkdustmagazine.com/features/linear-algebra-diagrams/)

Why is this true? 
For example, those in $(YB)$ correspond to the permutation $\rho$ on the three element set $\{0,1,2\}$ where $\rho(x)=2−x$

Comment: You want a proof of the yang-baxter equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us consider a symmetric group, $S_3$, where we will write $\sigma_1=(12)(3),\sigma_2=(1)(23)$. The symmetric group is memoryless, in the sense that $\sigma_i^2=(1)(2)(3)$, but the braid group is not.

We can draw diagrams just as they have, but in the case of braids, $\sigma_1,\sigma_2$ cross strands in a specific direction, and $\sigma_1^{-1},\sigma_2^{-1}$ cross in the opposite direction.

In the article, they simply use the symmetric group, where $\sigma_1\sigma_2\sigma_1=\sigma_2\sigma_1\sigma_2$ can easily be verified.

Indeed, one can track the three elements $\{1,2,3\}$ on their journey.

$$1\overset{\sigma_1}\mapsto 2\overset{\sigma_2}\mapsto3\overset{\sigma_1}\mapsto3$$
$$2\mapsto1\mapsto1\mapsto2$$
$$3\mapsto3\mapsto2\mapsto1$$

and
$$1\overset{\sigma_2}\mapsto1\overset{\sigma_1}\mapsto2\overset{\sigma_2}\mapsto3$$
$$2\mapsto3\mapsto3\mapsto2$$
$$3\mapsto2\mapsto1\mapsto1$$

Comment: Can you explain the verification ?

Comment: @user43418 See edit.